# Dynamically Add Text Files to DDL in ASP & VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am looking to update one of my DDL's functionality by making it dynamically update so if the user adds more files, the drop down will pick this up.

At present my drop down list is pulling from VB code behind, as shown below:

```
    Public Sub DDL_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim ddl As DropDownList = CType(sender, DropDownList) 'item is already dropdownlist
    Dim ctl As TextBox = DirectCast(ddl.NamingContainer.FindControl("eTemplate"), TextBox)
    If ddl.SelectedValue = 1 Then
        ctl.Text = File.ReadAllText("e:Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Web\Templates\Down.txt")
    ElseIf ddl.SelectedValue = 2 Then
        ctl.Text = File.ReadAllText("e:Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Web\Templates\Up.txt")

    Else
        ctl.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

At the moment I have hard coded in the functionality for the VB to grab specific .txt files, how can I get this to update dynamically from a folder of .txt files?

Thanks for looking.

Comment: You would need to implement some sort of Ajax to periodically refresh your dropdown list from the server. One (built-in) way would be to put it in an `UpdatePanel` in conjunction with a `Timer` control.

Comment: The whole drop down is on autopost back so would it need an AJAX call? If so, could you show me an example of how to go about this?

Comment: Yes it would. AutoPostBack will work only when user selects something in the DropdownList, isn't it? But you want to refresh the DropdownList as soon as a file is added in the folder.

Comment: Just added an answer with sample code :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some sample code for you. This demo uses an `UpdatePanel` and a `Timer` to refresh the DropdownList every 5 seconds.

Add a new aspx file to your Web Application and the following code:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Demo.aspx.vb" Inherits="Zpk_Test2" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Asynchronous Update Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager1" />
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" /><br />
                <asp:Timer runat="server" ID="Timer1" Interval="5000" Enabled="true" />
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDownList1" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="300" Height="250"  />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code-behind:

```
Partial Class Demo
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private Const FolderName As String = "C:\Temp"   '<-- replace with your folder name

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            RefreshDropDownList()
            OpenSelectedFile()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        ' this event is fired everytime a timer ticks. 
        ' refresh your dropdown list here.
        RefreshDropDownList()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged
        OpenSelectedFile()
    End Sub

    Private Sub RefreshDropDownList()
        Dim currentSelected As String = DropDownList1.SelectedValue
        DropDownList1.DataSource = IO.Directory.GetFiles(FolderName, "*.txt").Select(Function(f) IO.Path.GetFileName(f)).ToList
        DropDownList1.DataBind()
        DropDownList1.SelectedValue = currentSelected
    End Sub

    Private Sub OpenSelectedFile()
        Dim fileName As String = IO.Path.Combine(FolderName, DropDownList1.SelectedValue)
        TextBox1.Text = IO.File.ReadAllText(fileName)
    End Sub
End Class
```